# django tag "static" fails if url starts with "http://"

Tags: python, django, static

I want to allow loading file as from local as from external locations.

```
# template
{% static url %}
```

If `url` is `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js` I have in html this:

```
/static/http%3A//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js
```

but if `url` is `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js` I have proper link:

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js
```

Why? How can I avoid `/static/http%3A/`?

Answer (score 1):

Well you don't want to use the static tag for files hosted outside of your project. Just link that on your template like you would normally with a `<script src="`... type thing.

[Click here for the Django Documentation on this topic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/)

So that would be, in your HTML template, in the  tag you could put
`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>`

If what you're saying is you want to be able to change the URL dynamically or through some settings file, then you could do.

`<script src="{{ url }}"></script>`

Comment: `url` is parameter from app.settings. It may be as local as not.

Comment: What I'm saying is that you are breaking it by using {% static variable %} because that is for files that you're hosting yourself. I updated the original post to have an example of what you'd want to do to include a normal javascript file.

Comment: Well `{% static variable %}` is really just a helper. It uses `STATIC_URL` from your `settings.py` and just prepends it to whatever is in the variable, but it does some quick clean up things first which is what is messing your link up. So don't use `{% static url %}` unless it's files that are available from `STATIC_URL`

Comment: lampslave , you do not need to remove the http , you will have the same problem not you will end up with http://{static_url}/url. The idea is to replace the variable an html since this url is not one of the static files

Comment: What you want is `<script src="{{ url }}"></script>`

Comment: dusual, no! Maybe this is hack, but when url starts with `//`, {static_url} is not added. urlparse.urljoin do same, but for `http://` too.

Comment: Nothing passed to the `{% static url %}` template tag should have http:// or // in it. Just relative URLs that are relative to the `STATIC_URL` in your django settings file.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that makes sense doesn't it. You need to urlencode the resources that you are loading. These are resources that you need to serve for your website . For resources outside which you are refering through http are outside your app. Why can't you simply use simple html for that

Comment: I can't use html, because `url` is parameter from app.settings. User can change url as he wants.

Comment: Well that doesn't matter just url as the variable an html stormlifter has described things correctly for you. And is basically what i was aiming at as well